# Is there a not hand-waving way to prove any wheel graph is self-dual?

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked to present a self-dual graph of n vertices. An obvious choice would be a wheel of n vertices.

I think I should provide a proof that a wheel is self-dual; however, it seems so trivial/obvious that I cannot think of a way to prove it. (I was considering adjacency matrices, specify the center vertex and then assign rim vertices in order...etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don’t need to be too formal:

Embed it on a sphere with the central vertex at the north pole and the other vertices spaced around the Tropic of Capricorn at longitudes $\frac{360k}n$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$, if there are $n$ peripheral vertices. The dual graph is then naturally constructed with its central vertex at the south pole and its peripheral vertices on the Tropic of Cancer at longitudes $\frac{360k}n+\frac{180}n$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n-1$. This particular embedding makes the relationships that Alex Zorn mentions in his answer very easy to describe.

Comment: Ah, the balloon poking thing.

I really like this answer and the humor. A bit overkill, though.

Comment: In fact, it's always possible to embed a (connected, planar) self-dual graph on the sphere in such a way that a "rigid motion" carries the graph into "dual position". (This was the focus of my very first serious research project.)

Comment: @Blue: Now that’s interesting. I’m not at all sure that I’d have expected that.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It's one of my favorite discoveries. :) Proof sketch: draw $G$ on the plane, and draw the dual, $G^\star$ with vertices in $G$'s faces, edges crossing $G$'s edges. Introduce vertices where edges cross, subdividing those edges, to create $G^+$; note that $G^+$ admits an automorphism that carries the elements of $G$ onto the elements of $G^\star$ (and vice-versa). Throw in automorphism-preserving struts ---say, by constructing the Incidence Graph--- as needed to make $G^+$ 3-connected, then invoke Mani's Theorem ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: (continued) Mani's Theorem (a strengthening of Steinitz' Theorem) guarantees the existence of a convex polyhedron with vertices/edges/faces corresponding to those of a 3-connected graph, such that the *automorphisms* of the graph are induced by *isometries* of the polyhedron. So, take the Mani polyhedron for our super-graph, project it onto, say, an enveloping sphere, erase the struts and added vertices, and you have $G$ and $G^\star$ embedded in such a way that an isometry of the sphere carries $G$ onto $G^\star$. (Note that the edges almost-certainly have kinks.)

Comment: @Blue: Kinky! :-) Actually, very nice.

Answer (score 3):

1. Assign labels to the vertices.
2. Assign labels to the regions.
3. Say which regions are neighbors.
4. Describe a map Vertices -> Regions, and show that this induces an isomorphism between the graph and its dual.